# Find Pattern in Textfile From Several Elements In Several Lists?

Tags: python, regex, list

I am a beginner, been learning python for a few months as my very first programming language. I am looking to find a pattern from a text file. My first attempt has been using regex, which does work but has a limitation:

```
import re

noun_list = ['bacon', 'cheese', 'eggs', 'milk', 'list', 'dog']
CC_list = ['and', 'or']

noun_list_pattern1 = r'\b\w+\b,\s\b\w+\b,\sand\s\b\w+\b|\b\w+\b,\s\b\w+\b,\sor\s\b\w+\b|\b\w+\b,\s\b\w+\b\sand\s\b\w+\b|\b\w+\b,\s\b\w+\b,\saor\s\b\w+\b'

with open('test_sentence.txt', 'r') as input_f:
    read_input = input_f.read()
    word = re.findall(noun_list_pattern1, read_input)
    for w in word:
        print w
else:
    pass
```

So at this point you may be asking why are the lists in this code since they are not being used. Well, I have been racking my brains out, trying all sort of for loops and if statements in functions to try and find a why to replicate the regex pattern, but using the lists.

The limitation with regex is that the `\b\w+\w\` code which is found a number of times in `noun_list_pattern' actually only finds words - any words - but not specific nouns. This could raise false positives. I want to narrow things down more by using the elements in the list above instead of the regex.

Since I actually have 4 different regex in the regex pattern (it contains 4 `|`), I will just go with 1 of them here. So I would need to find a pattern such as:

`'noun in noun_list' + ', ' + 'noun in noun_list' + ', ' + 'C in CC_list' + ' ' + 'noun in noun_list`

Obviously, the above code quoted line is not real python code, but is an experession of my thoughts about the match needed. Where I say `noun in noun_list` I mean an iteration through the noun_list; `C in CC_list` is an iteration through the CC_list; `,` is a literal string match for a comma and whitespace.

Hopefully I have made myself clear!

Here is the content of the `test_sentence.txt` file that I am using:

```
I need to buy are bacon, cheese and eggs. 
I also need to buy milk, cheese, and bacon.
What's your favorite: milk, cheese or eggs.
What's my favorite: milk, bacon, or eggs.
```

Comment: Could you post an example of the data you want to match, please?

Comment: oops! yep will do, forgot about that.

Comment: Are you trying to analyze the structure of each sentence and group the similars together? If yes, you may want to try the nltk library:  http://nltk.org/ They also have a well written free document (comes as a book) as a beginner guide.

Comment: @Mai I did spend some time with nltk; however, I found that they were not perfect and correctly tokenizing a noun as a noun. So, I decided I would go with my own list of nouns. Pretty amazing, though, what nltk has going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break your problem down a little. First, you need a pattern that will match the words from your list, but no other. You can accomplish that with the alternation operator `|` and the literal words. `red|green|blue`, for example, will match `"red"`, `"green"`, or `"blue"`, but not `"purple"`. Join the noun list with that character, and add the word boundary metacharacters along with parentheses to group the alternations:

```
noun_patt = r'\b(' + '|'.join(nouns) + r')\b'
```

Do the same for your list of conjunctions:

```
conj_patt = r'\b(' + '|'.join(conjunctions) + r')\b'
```

The overall match you want to make is "one or more `noun_patt` match, each optionally followed by a comma, followed by a match for the `conj_patt` and then one more `noun_patt` match". Easy enough for a regex:

```
patt = r'({0},? )+{1} {0}'.format(noun_patt, conj_patt)
```

You don't really want to use `re.findall()`, but `re.search()`, since you're only expecting one match per line:

```
for line in lines:
...     print re.search(patt, line).group(0)
... 
bacon, cheese and eggs
milk, cheese, and bacon
milk, cheese or eggs
milk, bacon, or eggs
```

As a note, you're close to, if not rubbing up against, the limits of regular expressions as far as parsing English. Any more complex than this, and you will want to look into actual parsing, perhaps with NLTK.

Comment: Thanks Josh =) That is perfect. As a newb I wasn't aware of the `.format` method, very useful. I have also learned some neat stuff from the way you formatted the regex for the noun_patt and conj_patt lists. As I may need more the one match per line (or whole file) depending on how I read the file, then I can play around a little with `re.findall()` and `re.search()' to get what I need for any given situation. This regex approach is going to be super useful for other similar stuff I need. Thanks again =)

Comment: Josh, I am also wondering if you don't mind explaining to me the positioning of the parenthesis in `noun_patt` and `conj_patt`? I tried looking at the docs, but couldn't figure it out. My understanding was that parenthesis in regex only returned that part of the match, so is the code not returning the `\b`'s that sit outside the parenthesis? Also I'm curious about how the parenthesis are positioned between 2 single quotes, such as the `r'\b('` and `')\b'` segments of the `noun_patt` list. It is like the parenthesis 'hook in' inbetween the single quotes

Comment: 1 more thing =) I have tried this script by opening the text file with the `.read()` method, using the `re.findall()` function followed by a for loop to print each 'find' if the `re.findall()`. The result was a little off, but close. For some reason we get a duplicate noun, the first printed line: `('cheese ', 'cheese', 'and', 'eggs')`. We get 2 variants of 'cheese' - with and without a trailing space. The other printed lines following in the same suit. Not sure why using the `.read()` method changes how the regex matches? I played with the regex a little, to no desired result.

Comment: @Darren, the parentheses are to isolate the alternation of words from anything else that may show up next to the pattern when it's incorporated into the final pattern. The pipe has the lowest priority for binding, so if `milk|cheese` were inserted into the pattern as shown, the match would only succeed for `"milk"` or `"cheese,"`, but not `"milk,"`. Single quotes and double quotes are completely equivalent in Python, unlike C -- either one creates the same kind of string. So those operations just prepend and append strings consisting of a word boundary character and a parenthesis.

Comment: @Darren, because `findall()` doesn't return the entire match, it returns a tuple of the various match _groups_. The first group is `(noun_patt,? )`, which matches `"cheese "`. The second group is in `noun_patt` itself, and matches `"cheese"`. You should use `finditer()` if you want to scan the file as a single string.

Answer (score 2):

In actuality, you don't necessarily need regular expressions, as there are a number of ways to do this using just your original lists.

```
noun_list = ['bacon', 'cheese', 'eggs', 'milk', 'list', 'dog']
conjunctions = ['and', 'or']

#This assumes that file has been read into a list of newline delimited lines called `rawlines`
for line in rawlines:
    matches = [noun for noun in noun_list if noun in line] + [conj for conj in conjunctions if conj in line]
    if len(matches) == 4:
        for match in matches:
            print match
```

The reason the match number is 4, is that 4 is the correct number of matches. (Note, that this could also be the case for repeated nouns or conjunctions).

EDIT:

This version prints the lines that are matched and the words matched. Also fixed the possible multiple word match problem:

```
words_matched = []
matching_lines = []

for l in lst:
    matches = [noun for noun in noun_list if noun in l] + [conj for conj in conjunctions if conj in l]
    invalid = True
    valid_count = 0
    for match in matches:
        if matches.count(match) == 1:
            valid_count += 1
    if valid_count == len(matches):
        invalid = False

    if not invalid:
        words_matched.append(matches)
        matching_lines.append(l)

for line, matches in zip(matching_lines, words_matched):
    print line, matches
```

However, if this doesn't suit you, you can always build the regex as follows (using the `itertools` module):

```
#The number of permutations choices is 3 (as revealed from your examples)
for nouns, conj in itertools.product(itertools.permutations(noun_list, 3), conjunctions):
    matches = [noun for noun in nouns]
    matches.append(conj)
    #matches[:2] is the sublist containing the first 2 items, -1 is the last element, and matches[2:-1] is the element before the last element (if the number of nouns were more than 3, this would be the elements between the 2nd and last).
    regex_string = '\s,\s'.join(matches[:2]) + '\s' + matches[-1] + '\s' + '\s,\s'.join(matches[2:-1])
    print regex_string
    #... do regex related matching here
```

The caveat of this method is that it is pure brute-force as it generates all the possible combinations (read permutations) of both lists which can then be tested to see if each line matches. Hence, it is horrendously slow, but in this example that matches the ones given (the non-comma before the conjunction), this **will generate exact matches perfectly**.

Adapt as required.

Comment: Thanks for providing 2 detailed answers, I appreciate the help. I just tried your first code, the one that does not use regex, and it is printing this: 
`bacon` 
`cheese` 
`eggs`
`and`
`bacon`
`cheese`
`milk`
`and`
`cheese`
`eggs`
`milk`
`or`
`bacon`
`eggs`
`milk`
`or`

Each of those words are printed on a new line. What I was looking for is `bacon, cheese, and eggs` on one line as the first match, then `milk, cheese, and bacon` on the next line, etc.

Comment: (Also, interesting that your using the itertools permutations functions. I have that pegged for my longer term goals for this script in which I create all permutations and use them to replace the matches. But that is another day!)

Comment: @Darren: That's how I implemented it, as I interpreted it from your original question. The output that you quoted is the words that are found in each line from both the `nouns_list` and in `conjunctions`. That was mainly to verify the output. The logic I used was that if those words were in the line (numbered 4), then that is a match - which is what you wanted, correct? Or, have I unfortunately misinterpreted your question?

Comment: It was probably my lack of explaining, because Josh Cashwell's answer below was also producing the same result of per word per line! In my original example, the regex produces exact matches for phrases, not individual words, which is what I was looking for. Sorry for any confusion :(

Comment: @Darren: Actually, both of our examples match all the words. Josh's solution generates a regex based on the words, as does mine. But, I've edited my solution as (correct me if I am wrong), **you want the line that is matched, and not the words that are matched** - correct?

Comment: jrd1 - thanks for the edit! Almost there. It is not the line that I want printed/returned, but the exact phrase `bacon, cheese, and eggs`, etc. I don't mind if that is through opening the text file in line delimited format, or reading the whole file using the `.read()` method. I just want to get my hands on the phrases exactly as they appear in the text file. So if a line reads `I need to buy are bacon, cheese and eggs.`, then I need the exact match of `bacon, cheese and eggs` extracted. I will then later do stuff to these exatch matches.

Comment: Also, I will add, that I will be using this for bigger .txt files, with a considerably larger list of nouns

Comment: @Darren: Ah! I see. Then you do need `regexes` after all. In that case Josh's answer is the way to go. :)

Comment: Thanks jrd1 - you have been an awesome help! Your use of for loops for creating the variable `matches` has been particularly illuminating =)